# A way to add markup to gist in http://gist.github.com/?

Tags: github, gist

Seems like a lot of people use gists for cheatsheets, including me, so something like code line wrapping would be nice! Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Name your text file as `example.markup-name`.

For a list of markup-names:

https://github.com/github/markup

Comment: .md - is works for me

https://gist.github.com/TheRatG/ac92045ae96d7a68bad70aaaf0a3be14

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just select the "markdown" language option, and mark it up using [GitHub-flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/). Here's an [example](http://gist.github.com/479292).

Comment: gists uses standard markdown.  Comments of gists do use GFM, though.

Comment: this was the behavior i was looking for when trying to share a text snippet w a friend. sure, it didn't break the lines so they could edit them -- but it's readable.